# Is there an accepted definition of what a “shortage” is in economics?

Tags: definition

Laymen often talk about “shortages” in the economy. But is there an accepted definition of what a “shortage” is from the perspective of economics as a science?

Comment: Hi! Can you please explain what you mean by "accepted definition"?

Comment: Hi @JonathanReez. Shortage is not a term used in the typical textbook, I wouldn't imagine. But it is pervasive nevertheless. It's most commonly used to characterise the compound effect of: (1) excess demand for a good/service/production input, often in conjunction with (2) inelastic supply of some good/service/input.

Comment: @EB3112 what are you talking about? Term shortage is used in every economics textbook, what textbook you used that did not mentioned it? Every textbook I know mentions shortages when discussing price floors which is part of core 101 economics

Comment: Hi @WilliamT. If I mispoke regarding the frequency of 'shortage' used in undergrad texts, then I apologise to the OP. However, my comment is not only consistent with your own answer, but consistent too with Mankiw who refers to shortage as `excess demand.' So, you caught me: I don't cradle my copy of Mankiw in bed at night like you do. But, my original comment was nevertheless informative to the OP. There are counterexamples (a copy of a textbook in front of me) does not mention the word shortage once, yet mentions excess demand 23 times. https://andrewclausen.net/teaching/econtheory.pdf

Comment: @EB3112 I do not cradle economic textbooks in bed either, but I wanted to correct the record

Answer (score 1):

Shortage is in economics textbooks defined as the positive difference between quantity demanded and quantity supplied. If the difference is negative it will be called surplus.

**shortage:** $Q_d - Q_s >0$

**surplus:** $Q_d - Q_s <0$

This is how I saw it defined in every economics textbook I ever used. For example, Soloman's Economics, or Mankiw's Principles.